# batch file to assign in task file

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have 1 file with `DT"ddmmyyyy".xlsx` and I want this file to copy everyday and paste in same folder with today's date.

i.e today date is `12DEC2023` then command should be
 `copy "DT11122023.xlsx" "DT12122023.xlsx"`

---

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ('powershell Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyy"') do (
    set "today=%%a%%b%%c"
)
set /a "yesterday=%today%-1"

copy "DT%yesterday%.xlsx" "DT%today%.xls"
```

I want yesterday date file to copy and paste in same folder with today date

Comment: Your code snippet produces `copy "DT11122022.xlsx" "DT11122023.xls"` (i.e. *a year ago* instead of *yesterday*). Do all in a PowerShell script instead of `batch` one…

Answer (score 0):

If you insist upon a `batch-file` script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('
  powershell -NoProfile -Command "& {Write-Output """"today=$(Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy) yesterday=$(Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy -Date (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))""""}"
  ') do (
        set "%%a"
        set "%%b"
    )

ECHO copy /B "DT%yesterday%.xlsx" "DT%today%.xlsx"
```

**Output** (remove word `ECHO` as soon as debugged):

```
.\SO\77642167.bat
```

> ```
> copy "DT10122023.xlsx" "DT11122023.xls"
> ```